# Setting context of a spinner control in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner, android-context

I've rigged together the `TabActivity` solution [described here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) but of course since it is a hacky approach there are issues involving the context of controls. In particular, dialogs and spinners do not behave well and crash at runtime because the context is wrong. I want my `Spinner`'s context to be `getParent()`, but I am not aware of a way of setting the spinner's context outside of it's constructor. I do not explicitly call the constructor at this time because I am wiring up the spinner using `findViewById`. Is there some way of adjusting the `Spinner`'s context? Here is my current code:

```
    categorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
    categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list3);
    categoryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    categorySpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

    categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getActivity() is your friend in these situations.  That will let you set the context to the current activity.

Comment: I used a variant of this idea...`View viewToLoad = mInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.resource_filter, null);
        setContentView(viewToLoad);`

Comment: where to put the getActivity() to set the spinner Context to getParent()? LayoutInflater seems working, but I can't use LayoutInflater, it will cause other problems to other part of my code

Comment: It wouldbe the first parameter when you make the call for the adapter that puts data into the spinner.